# Issue using AsyncTypeahead from react-bootstrap-typeahead package

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, bootstrap-typeahead

I'm having an issue using the `AsyncTypeahead` from the `react-bootstrap-typeahead` project, where it seems like my `onSearch` handler is not getting called. I can see the typeahead on the page, but when I type in it, `handleSearch` is not being executed and I don't see any console logging. Here's a short example:

```js
import React, {PropTypes, Component} from 'react';
import AsyncTypeahead from 'react-bootstrap-typeahead';
class CustomTypeahead extends Component {
  
  state = { results: [] }
  
  handleSearch(event) {
    console.log("Show me what you got")
    // fetch data here and set state to results in a promise
    // this.setState(results)
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <AsyncTypeahead
          onSearch={this.handleSearch.bind(this)}
          options={this.state.results}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Any suggestions or insights are really appreciated!!!

Comment: This ended up being an issue with the version I was using versus the docs I was reading! Always check the version....

Answer (score 2):

Fixed by using:

```
import { AsyncTypeahead } from 'react-bootstrap-typeahead';
```

instead of

```
import AsyncTypeahead from 'react-bootstrap-typeahead';
```

and updating to version ^1.0.0 for `react-bootstrap-typeahead`